# how do I delete a column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

path_brent = "/Users/alfredolucente/Documents/MCOILBRENTEU.csv"
path_natgas = "/Users/alfredolucente/Documents/PNGASEUUSDM.csv"

brent_prices = pd.read_csv(path_brent, delimiter=";")
natgas_prices = pd.read_csv(path_natgas, delimiter=";")

print(brent_prices.head(10))
print(natgas_prices.head(10))

brent_prices_2 = brent_prices.drop("DATE", inplace=True, axis=1)
print(brent_prices_2)
```

```
   DATE,MCOILBRENTEU
0  1987-05-01,18.58
1  1987-06-01,18.86
2  1987-07-01,19.86
3  1987-08-01,18.98
4  1987-09-01,18.31
5  1987-10-01,18.76
6  1987-11-01,17.78
7  1987-12-01,17.05
8  1988-01-01,16.75
9  1988-02-01,15.73
   DATE,PNGASEUUSDM
0  1990-01-01,1.72999996609158
1  1990-02-01,1.72999996609158
2  1990-03-01,1.72999996609158
3  1990-04-01,2.10999976264106
4  1990-05-01,2.10999976264106
5  1990-06-01,2.10999976264106
6  1990-07-01,1.91999986436632
7  1990-08-01,1.91999986436632
8  1990-09-01,1.91999986436632
9  1990-10-01,2.37999979654948
```

The code above is trying to get only the price column by using the `drop()` function, but I keep getting:

> ['DATE'] not found in axis

Comment: `inplace=True` with an assignment to `brent_prices_2` seems awkward at best, and a lurking bug.

Comment: Can you show the output of `print(brent_prices.columns)`?

Comment: Since you specify the delimiter as ';', your column name is probably `DATE,MCOILBRENTEU`, *including* the comma, and the column data is, for example, `1987-05-01,18.58`, again including the comma (i.e., a string).

Answer (score 1):

Your data is delimeted by `,`, not `;`. As you can see in your output, your data is therefore not seperated correctly and you have a single column named `"DATE,MCOILBRENTEU"`.

Change

```
brent_prices = pd.read_csv(path_brent, delimiter=";")
natgas_prices = pd.read_csv(path_natgas, delimiter=";")
```

To

```
brent_prices = pd.read_csv(path_brent, delimiter=",")
natgas_prices = pd.read_csv(path_natgas, delimiter=",")
```